# Has an object been observed falling inside the black hole in direction antiparallel to an astrophysical jet?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, astrophysics, relativistic-jets

Has an object been observed falling inside the black hole in direction antiparallel to an astrophysical jet? I do not know if the jet is fighting against gravity or not so will that part around the black hole force the falling object to be ejected in direction of the jet and accordingly move that object away?

Comment: As this seems to be claimed as a first observation of an inflow of gas towards a black hole, https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/481/2/1832/5090165 I doubt that interference with outflow (astrophysical jet) inflow interference has been observed up to now.

Answer (score 2):

An astrophysical jet forms when matter is accreted onto a black hole from an accretion disk.

The only thing that matters about the jet direction is the accretion disk: The jet is perpendicular to the accretion disk.
This is because of the magnetic  field of the disk, whose field lines converge perpendicular to the accretion disk. These field lines determine the direction the direction of the jet.

Now, if matter is falling onto the black hole antiparallel to the jet, its flow will be redirected onto the accretion disk due to the magnetic field and the loss of angular momentum.

If an object if falling through the jet (speaking hypothetically, of course), then it will slow down the jet (based on its size) and form a shock boundary consisting of jet matter interacting with the body. For example, consider the interaction of supermassive black hole jets with the surrounding intergalactic medium.

Hope this helps!